# How do I insert a background image for a horizontal rule?

Tags: html, css, background-image

How do I insert a background image for a horizontal rule? I know you have to insert a URL, but my background image is in a local file. Can I use a local file?

Comment: Are you, on your local computer, the only one going to see this webpage? If not, no, you can't use a local file; it has to be as accessible at the time of viewing as any other part of the page.

Comment: background-image: url(<path to image, can be relative or absolute/image name>);

Comment: @amyjamietara hi you can find various way of showing image **https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/css/backp4.php**

Comment: Thank you. What I would like to do is have a hr with a single image in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an inline CSS like this.
 `<hr style="border:0; height:15px; background:url(images/pic.png) 50% 0 no-repeat; margin:1em 0;">` 
Here the url is the file path to your picture. I have used a relative path assuming there is a folder called "images" in your current file location. "pic.png" must be inside that folder. To see this, the folder and the file must be there with the code. I think I understood your question.
Note: change other css parameters according to your image.

Comment: Thank you. What I would like to do is have a hr with a single image in the middle.

Comment: I'm not clear what do you actually want. I've never seen such hr. Anyway https://css-tricks.com/simple-styles-for-horizontal-rules/ this link contains a hr with a character in the middle. But I think that's not what you really want.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is what I mean. But I would like to use my own image.